# Не всегда приходит ответ

Tags: windows, сокеты, c

Вот программа на сокетах `windows`, которая по задумке должна выводить `HTML` код с порта 80    запрашиваемого `ip`.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 32768
#define DEFAULT_PORT "80"

int __cdecl main() {
re:
    //----------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct sockaddr_in clientService;

char *sendbuf = "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

//----------------------
// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
  printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
  return 1;
}

//----------------------
// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

//----------------------
// The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
// IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "91.000.000.00" );
clientService.sin_port = htons( 80 );

//----------------------
// Connect to server.
iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    closesocket (ConnectSocket);
    printf("Unable to connect to server: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Send an initial buffer
iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
    { printf("Connection closed\n"); printf(recvbuf);}
    else
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while( iResult > 0 );

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();
system("pause");
goto re;
    return 0;
}
```

Не только при каждой 5-10 попытке приходит код. В чём проблема?

## upd

1Ѓ^Ээј‡rG0ЏУfд‚Aо9KПIґ#{РM}ЏоЭ-ЮЫMяЎ°чѓ™={†ЪШwх“ЅДѕ`(Cz)·Іґd[я ЊFї•J«мЭC^IQP‹e
Й™Є№АЌЮ€Ы•ј‘Э€Q/DvcAЉ»аm+Ґќl‹з   µ%5_hX‰‘xЁЧЉ‰ЏЏШ|пЂИЌg@^т@ГЧ
?AYЌђЫцЧUct‰ I&«Eђ1mzPЭ*jr…‡ЗVs е^B®‹
ЃТЅ+o~#UтK|r/В7b)ь)ћџKЉ*ЦD0UџьтЛР€р\!±vkюА ›Ј«aќЙVEЮєuRyМ@QБ02F—9U0т D§^ЫњЎЛцДЭYYZЙ$УќQЧvqйґ/Ћ—МСоH»2цJ3цвк“ЙЂћд8(}ОєХ·№°“ющ8
ЌIТhMАhај®  їa›ћЬ?ї@jrЬё­М<ЪћіэъEоQjЬвKмМFзEOфѕ9±bNOс.A<ІяоЗџ|xзГ»Ц¤фЮ=М'Vњp~CДC’СO&
и]®±‡РKШРh«ѓљйзѕµ-Г›GЌьR
4шпрСВн‘G«Qы<}РЕ…ЫЦ/ф0r‚3АR"ёїАM*`њЕь5}ж,‡=Uђ‘Ф(Й„тY}И4H&зиЁЈл[>Ъя¬ќЗ«Б¤*Г.+@¬і›ѕ3ЁЦВѓЙ©1¦&Y+РZkx¤X;ИМ„]ёe€Ќ_•АЬњщwЌrЊ¤fВ5/~­ЊёТЎ\яJ¬l­ЇПS¬QђщчЯ!шО:>b'ґТ^ZШгшІVg±HА№liШvћsЇрпдњ€МRЁDЈшHPJ[Ґ-e»ґµmїq   Н/Э(I›9x—аЎ–с™F4%ђ„7ЯЊТЙ9c 2$ДкГyЫмy,Mr—#z‹3»ФЖ$‚LNТГжРЄ8ВfЗ¦Цѕ@c]Љі
mnМЈы=‰а¤M)`фІ
ѓ{вАkl„ІЕp;р­мзНzQ¦CѕB
^л/Q’п–ќ‡КW ›t-ђчњП#)ФП;-!`>SE"ЪОђВ-wтъP†0Vж&К‚тЛЅЪ
t<Ф}F}*¶Z‰-rMщЏ‘W+8п>)КтЋ$&`а‚1PЊўGщҐёэйэz4ЅЅъЯ“ш`нлЇ•"а"yiЩVЋдЭЇг_'ѕѕщхч’Ыа|эх{п3‡
у}эх:юZwяыЪЅинwЦ>АЇ·Ђ»H"пҐ#оЙљхyуy±#оу­Oџ•8ЃЊ­i№[ѕSп%Ѓ*uШЇЭlЇБ‹дВ]Vа=фРьXTј>F”ї*M_нb
АЪЯ®PPгєЄ€+оё–В¦Xз›П(cxшdДяЦ4Є|,XвXЬК„YҐ3‹дЧлЙн3
5iKІl«$е— !Vе]сВыPђ„йBXиџШбBьхХ[b%OаЪdLk=Ш6,ђ8IPС¬kDј_—АЪУ¶JPеїъЕќЇШeFS4t<>q#:EлСNfїµ0gµ/`=и’»{ъ‚_ѓ>ф®ќ‡U·ДЊрљП-ou=вЎчM®Й$И†ЦЪC$мљ8фѓљ•0dЉAф„g~јВѕ`ОЃmGeЊЃ(:пHе?ІЏЄшжVп,Еf'чљХо!Эпѕ’L
РЁќ9®*k>ГtTU6Rдэч‰+э­l
?юж

Comment: А в остальных попытках что происходит?

Comment: на самом деле гениальный вопрос=)

Comment: @avp 
    Bytes received: %рандомное число, обычно в пределах 300-1500%  
     Connection closed

Comment: И чем Вам это не нравится? Вы эти быйты распечатайте и посмотрите.

Тут дело скорее всего в том, что надо почитать о протоколе HTTP.

 Насколько помню, в HTTP/1.1 в заголовках запроса по крайней мере еще поле

    HOST: ip или имя с кем соединяетесь (точнее от кого ответ хотите почить)

должно быть.

Comment: @avp, передавал хттп заголовки в точности так-же как это делает ие10. Просто в вопросе убрал, не хотел светить хост, к которому подключаюсь. А распечатать это в смысле на принтере?

Comment: @ололо Это в смысле посмотреть глазами, что именно пришло в текстовом формате.

Comment: @avp, вот что пишет в файл из recvbuf (upd)

Comment: м, может это gzip?

Comment: @KoVadim, скорее всего. А как расшифровать можно?

Comment: расшифровать можно. Но только там вначале должен прийти читаемый заголовок. [детали](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).